# web application in different sso federations

Tags: single-sign-on

is it possible include one web application into several sso federations

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least in the SAML-P and WS-Federation protocols there is nothing that forbids this.  A web application can inspect the incoming HTTP request (the URL and/or cookies), and use that to choose the STS to redirect to.

However, a specific SSO library/framework might have restrictions in this area.

For example, if your web application is in .NET based on WIF, then the [`WSFederationAuthenticationModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule_members.aspx) has exactly one `Issuer`, which is used for all sign-in requests.  (This is usually set in the `web.config` file in the `<wsFederation issuer="...">` attribute).  It *may* be possible to override the `CreateSignInRequest()` method of this module, temporarily setting `Issuer` to a different value while the request is created (and applying the proper locking).  But WIF was apparently not designed to support this multi-SSO-federation scenario.